# While in debug mode, can I cause the debugger to break (ie:pause) when some piece of C#/VB.NET code executes SQL Insert?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, debugging

I'm debugging a legacy application that I'm not very familiar with. Using SQL profiler, I know it's inserting an undeseriable value into a table/column. I need to know where in C#/VB.NET code it's generating/executing the SQL insert statement so I can remove this unwanted value.

Is there a way I can get the debugger to break/pause on each insert event so that I can crawl up the call stack and find the offending c#/vb.net code?

Comment: Can't you search the codebase for every call to `ExecuteNonQuery` and set a breakpoint there?

Comment: I tried that already.. there are just way too many matches on `ExecuteNonQuery` to sift through and the code is pretty complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [.NET Framework Source Stepping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source) then step in to the code for `SqlCommand` once you will then be able to put breakpoints in the `SqlCommand.cs` file, You can put a breakpoint on each of the Execute methods and then your program will cause the debugger to break on each call to sql query executed.

Another option is enable "[Diagnostic Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210448.aspx)" from there you can go to the "Events" tab have it filter to show just all ADO.NET operations, once you see the query you are looking for goes by you can click on it and it will take you to the code that executed that query.

Comment: I checked "Enable .NET framework source stepping"  in Tools -> Options -> Debugging and "Microsoft Symbol Servers" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols but that didn't work. I tested this using a new console project that calls into `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Also I couldn't view any ADO.NET operations in the Events tab. I think this feature only works with VS Enterprise edition - I only have VS Professonal.

Comment: Double check you are doing the correct steps to set it up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source, Also check these insturctions too http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html. Lastly, according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source/ you should NOT check the box for "Microsoft Symbol Servers" that causes the pdbs that do not have source to be downloaded.

Comment: I followed all the steps in the links you have provided and it still doesn't work. I did notice in fiddler, VS2017 is getting 404 errors when hitting referencesource.microsoft.com. Here's a screenshot of my logs
https://imgur.com/VFDG9T4